# VBA - Change formulas in a range

Tags: excel, vba

So i would like to know how i could update the formulas in a range (E7:BE7), in my sheet i have multiple tables so i can't update it with lastRow.

For each cell in the range E7:BE7 i have these formulas :

- =SUM(E8:E15)
- =SUM(F8:F15)
- ...
- =SUM(BE8:BE15)

after using a script to add a new entry to the table i would like to update the formulas so that the last row is incremented by one. So i would have all of the formulas in that range become like this after a new entry :

- =SUM(E8:E16)
- =SUM(F8:F16)
- ...
- =SUM(BE8:BE16)

Here's a snippet of my script that adds a new entry, i would like to automatically update those formulas, but i'm still new to vba and struggling a bit, any help would be appreciated.

```
        With Target
            Dim cell As Range
            Dim calendar_header As Range
            
            Set calendar_header = Range("E7:BE7")
            
            ' this is the part that will insert a new row on my target and copy the information i need in the row
            .Offset(0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Offset(-2).EntireRow.Copy
            .Offset(-1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cells(.Row - 1, "A").Value = Cells(.Row - 2, "A").Value
            Cells(.Row - 1, "B").Value = Cells(.Row - 2, "B").Value
            Cells(.Row - 2, "E").Copy
            Cells(.Row - 1, "E").PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            ' This is the loop that's supposed to make my updates on the formulas
            For Each cell In calendar_header
                
                 ' Im struggling with this part.
                
            Next cell
            
            
        End With
```

Comment: Generally i would suggest that you should qualify your `Range` but you probably would get away with it in this instance. You don't need a loop to update the formula. Presuming that your `Target` is the last row, you could just do this: `calendar_header.Formula = "-SUM(E$8:E$" & Target.Row & ")"`. This will update the formula in your range

Comment: Hi Zac, thanks a lot ! I actually had multiple tables but i didn't want to have the whole answer given to me since i'm trying to learn so i simplified my example, i got what i needed from you and now i can update the headers of my different tables ! I can't really put a comment as the answer to my question, can you put what you wrote as an answer so i can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop to update the formula. Presuming that your `Target` is the last row, you could just do this: `calendar_header.Formula = "-SUM(E$8:E$" & Target.Row & ")"`. This will update the formula in your range

**NOTE:** Also consider what happense if `Target` has more than 1 cell

Comment: Nice. Sometimes developers forget about that scenario. Good luck